# Nestjs bullmq worker processor don't works with jest

Tags: jestjs, nestjs, bullmq

### Step to reproduce

1. Create a new nest project : `nest new nest-app`
2. Install dependencies : `npm i @nestjs/bullmq ioredis`
3. Start a redis instance on default port 6379
4. Create this 2 files

app.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Job, Queue, Worker } from 'bullmq';
import Redis, { RedisOptions } from 'ioredis';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  private queue: Queue;
  private worker: Worker;
  private redis: Redis;

  connect() {
    const redisConfig: RedisOptions = {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 6379,
      autoResubscribe: false,
      lazyConnect: true,
      maxRetriesPerRequest: 0,
      reconnectOnError: null,
      enableOfflineQueue: true,
    };
    this.redis = new Redis(redisConfig);
    this.queue = new Queue('queue1', { connection: this.redis });
    this.worker = new Worker(
      'queue1',
      async (job) => {
        console.log('PROCESS')
        await this.wait({});
        console.log('DONE')
        return job;
      },
      { connection: this.redis },
    );
    // Replace by this line and it works
    // this.worker = new Worker('queue1', '', { connection: this.redis });
  }

  async disconnect(): Promise<void> {
    await this.queue.close();
    await this.worker.close();
    await this.redis.quit();
  }

  async wait({ seconds = 1 }: { seconds?: number }): Promise<void> {
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, seconds * 1000));
  }
}
```

app.service.spec.ts

```js
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

describe('Queue Service', () => {
  let appService: AppService;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [AppService],
    }).compile();
    appService = module.get<AppService>(AppService);
    appService.connect();
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await appService.disconnect();
  });

  it('Should pass', async () => {
    expect(true).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

### Actual result

The test is still running with

```
Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.

'This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.
```

### Expected result

The test just succeed

### Versions

node : 16.20.1

npm : 9.8.1

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/bullmq": "^10.0.1",
    "@nestjs/common": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^10.0.0",
    "ioredis": "^5.3.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^10.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^20.3.1",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.12",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.59.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.59.11",
    "eslint": "^8.42.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "prettier": "^2.8.8",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.21",
    "supertest": "^6.3.3",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `Jest` process was shutdown before `disconnect()` function promise was resolved.

Try

```js
afterAll(async () => {
  await appService.disconnect();
});
```

Also add `--detectOpenHandles` to jest execution in `package.json`

Example:

```
"test:e2e": "jest --detectOpenHandles --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
```

[image]

Comment: just forgot it but there is still the issue

Comment: Still the same issue?

Comment: yes I've tested outside nestjs and it works but not with nest

Comment: I think, there also should be await before connect. I see there are also async operations

Comment: connect is not async, where you able to reproduce it ?

Comment: @TheSmartMonkey but new Worker callback is async. It is not called during it's init, right?

Comment: yes it's a processor it's a function that is only called when you create a new job from what I understand but I may be wrong

Comment: Can you just try also await for connect to exclude this possibility?

Comment: just tryed same issue :(

Comment: @TheSmartMonkey I've set up everything you described and test passed for me. Maybe redis is hung or smth like that?

Comment: @TheSmartMonkey this was slient warning in my case. Was able to solve it by adding `--detectOpenHandles` for jest execution in `package.json`

Comment: It didn't solve the issue in my case

Comment: @TheSmartMonkey has it pointed to an issue? Or just failed? Also, can you kill redis and launch again?

Comment: If I had --detectOpenHandles it only removes the warning but the test is still stuck with an async process

Comment: So, I set up your infra in package.json, and used you npm / node versions and still test passes. So I have 2 last conclusions
1. After detectOpenHandles try `--testTimeout=25000`
2. You have another tests in you package and one of them has unresolved promise. But this test runs last in queue, so fails this one and not the one with unresolved promise.